# Namespace en PHP

Tags: php, poo, namespace

Trabajo con ***namespace*** pero leyendo en la documentación observe una función con los **namespace** llamada **use** pero no entiendo muy bien cual es el trasfondo de esta misma, entiendo que se pueden declarar como una especie de **foreach** cambiando hasta el nombre de la clase o de la función que se necesita, pero también quiero saber si este puede hacer uso de otros **namespace** sin necesidad de usar el **include** o el **requiere** solo con el nombre de espacio encontrar la clase que especifico.

**Ejemplo de lo que pienso:**

```
<?php
namespace model\controller\namespace_requerido use clase_necesitada;

class foo
{
  static function método_estático() {}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los `namespace` son ruta donde esta almacenada la clase, básicamente seria

`class/miclase.php`

dentro de miclase.php

```
namespace class;
class Miclase{
//codigo...
}
```

ahora bien, digamos que tienes un subdirectorio que seria `class/util` y dentro tengas la clase `miutilitario.php` el `namespace` para esta clase seria;

```
namespace class\util;
class MiUtilitario{
//codigo...
}
```

> Date cuenta que se usa la barra invertida para especificar el
>   `namespace`

esto te sirve para cuando hay clases con el mismo nombre no se produzca un choque, como por ejemplo al intentar tener 2 archivos con el mismo nombre y misma extensión en windows.

Los frameworks utilizan estos para auto cargar las clases con la palabra reservada `use` aunque puedes crear tu mismo tu propio cargador de clases gracias a `spl_autoload_register`.

Esto cuando instancias una clase y no la encuentra le da una "segunda" oportunidad y por su 'namespace' carga la clase y de existir pues la clase es instanciada.

Cuando necesito `miutilitario` en otro archivo basta con decirle;

```
use class\util\MiUtilitario;

class MiController{

public function algo(){

}
  $util = new MiUtilitario();
  //codigo....
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de un autocargador que uso en [mi framework](https://github.com/itsalb3rt/ligne_php)(Elimine algunas cosas para no confundirte);

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register('_autoload');

// Constante para reemplazar el slash invertido del namespace
define('DS','/');

function _autoload( $class ) {
    $class = ROOT  . str_replace("\\",DS,$class) . '.php';

    if(!file_exists($class)){
        echo "Error al cargar la clase " . $class;
        die();
    }else{
        require_once($class);
    }
}
```

**En resumen:**
El `namespace` es una ruta donde se almacenan las clases y el `use` ayuda al autocargador a cargar la clase que necesitas.

El `required` o el `include` continúan estando allí, solo que están en una capa de abstracción gracias al auto cargador, con esto creamos código mas limpio y escalable.

**Extra**

El autocargador va antes de cualquier cosa que se ejecuta;

```
require_once(ROOT . 'Core/System/Core/autoload.php');
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por el ejemplo tan detallado amigo, y mas el plus del autoload , creo que esto me va a servir también para un proyecto que tengo en MVC para cambiar cargar los namespace de las clases en el núcleo de mi MVC, gracias ¡CRACK!.

Comment: @JeanCarloCastañoMillan Me alegra que te sirva, ahora bien hay estanderes como por ejemplo, 1 archivo de clase solo debe tener 1 clase no mas, convenciones de nombre de clases y directorios contenedores de clases, por ejemplo `dir/vendor/jeanCarlo` y algunas cosas extras que puedes indagar buscando en la red sobre los estándares de php moderno

Answer (score 0):

Ahora respondiendo yo mismo a mis inquietudes me puse a la tarea de hacer un ejemplo sencillo.Supongamos que tenemos una carpeta llamada ***clases*** y dentro de esta misma tenemos el archivo nuestro archivo ***Amigo.php***

```
introducir el código aquí

clases => **Carpeta**
Amigo.php => Archivo que contiene la carpeta clases.
```

En nuestro archivo ***Amigo.php*** tenemos esta estructura

```
introducir el código aquí
namespace saludoEspañol;
class Amigo1{
  private $jean;
  public function __construct()
  {
    return $this->jean = "Hola amigos";
  }
}
namespace saludoIngles;
class Amigo2{
  private $jean;
  public function __construct()
  {
    return $this->jean = "Hello friends";
  }
}
```

***Nota:*** supongamos que queremos tener el saludo en ***español*** e ***ingles*** y sus valores utilizarlos en otras partes sin necesidad de repetirlos en la misma clase, podemos separarlos con un ***namespace*** para que se pueda utilizar en otros lados y tengamos usos independientes de este mismo.

Si pueden notar en el ejemplo anterior tengo ***2 namespaces*** uno se llama ***saludoEspañol*** que tiene una clase llamada ***Amigo1***, y mas abajo declaramos otro namespace llamado ***saludoIngles*** y una clase llamada ***Amigo2***, si tenemos en cuenta esto significa que la funcionalidad que contienen son *similares* pero sus valores *distintos*, porque mientras uno saluda en ingles el otro saluda en español pero esta funcionalidad solo lo acobija hasta donde se encuentre el *namespace* , en otras palabras después de que se declaro el segundo namespace ya la funcionalidad siguiente no hará parte del anterior

```
introducir el código aquí
namespace saludoEspañol;
class Amigo1{
  private $jean;
  public function __construct()
  {
    return $this->jean = "Hola amigos";
  }
}
/*Aqui termina mi namespace saludoEspañol */ 
namespace saludoIngles;
/*Aqui comienza mi namespace saludoIngles */
class Amigo2{
  private $jean;
  public function __construct()
  {
    return $this->jean = "Hello friends";
  }
}
```

Continuando con el ejemplo si queremos hacer uso de estos saludos los requerimos en un archivo por fuera de la carpeta **clases** y incluimos nuestra clase **Amigo.php**

```
introducir el código aquí
require('clases/Amigo.php');

use saludoEspañol as español;
use saludoIngles  as ingles;


print_r($objeto = new español\Amigo1());

print_r($objeto2 = new ingles\Amigo2());
```

Concluyendo con mi ejemplo requiero mi archivo de la *clase Amigo* que esta en la carpeta **clases** y con **use** llamo a mi **namespace** y le asigno un **"apodo"** con **as** como lo hicimos cambiando en saludoEspañol su nombre a **español** para que sea mas facil o mas corto utilizarlo, hago lo mismo con el segundo *namespace*, y por ultimo capturo sus valores en una variable llamada *objeto* que crea una *instancia* de mi clase, primero llama al *namespace* con el apodo que le pusimos nuevo y después llama a la clase **Amigo1** y como su *metodo* retorna un *objeto* lo mostramos en pantalla con un *print_r()*.

El resultado de lo anterior sera esto:

```
introducir el código aquí

saludoEspañol\amigo1 Object ( [jean:saludoEspañol\amigo1:private] => Hola amigos )
saludoIngles\amigo2 Object ( [jean:saludoIngles\amigo2:private] => Hello friends )
```